# how to get snmp hostname along with results in the output that i am querying

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

Folks,

I'm trying snmpget and snmpwalk to get values from a device as shown below. But i need values and hostname that i am querying as a output.

```
snmpget -v2c -c CommunityString HOSTNAME .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.1.1.1.1.1
```

Current OUTPUT i'm getting:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1 = value: 7116
```

Expected OUTPTU I need :

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1 = value: 7116 HOSTNAME
```

(i need hostname along with results)

I also tested sysName.0 no luck.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i got it:

snmpget -v2c -c CommunityString HOSTNAME .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.1.1.1.1.1 sysName.0